# How to mount a hidden NTFS WinRE which are on an external HDD

Tags: mount, ntfs

A friend have given me her external hard drive which contains a backup of his Windows data. The disk has two NTFS partitions, once of them tagged as WinRe.

When I do

```
fdisk -lu
```

I get

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x59725972

Dispositiu Arrenc.  Inici       Final       Blocs    Id  Sistema
/dev/sdc1            2048     3074047     1536000    27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdc2   *     3074048   234438655   115682304     7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I never fought against this type of partitions and I haven't any idea of how to mount this and recover the data.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Since you know the filesystem type and location, can you just not mount it normally with `sudo mkdir /mnt/winre; sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sdc1 /mnt/winre`?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) is a set of tools included in the Windows Vista, and newer operating systems to help diagnose and recover from serious errors that may prevent Windows from booting successfully. When this is installed, reboot and press F8 in order to boot into this Recovery Environment.  Therefore I don't think that it can be mounted, and even if it could it will not have any user data in it.